# Has Anybody Built A Raspberry Pi Inside A Mouse Yet?

Tags: raspbian, wireless, keyboard, mouse, case

I was wondering if anybody has thought of putting a Raspberry Pi inside a mouse yet?  i.e. wireless display and keyboard and the raspberry pi case is the mouse.

Just thought it would be a cool project.

Comment: You'd have to find an unusually large mouse to fit it in inside the chasis, or adapt one somehow.

Comment: While not using a Raspberry Pi, I just came across this PC in a mouse in an email from O'Reilly http://mybroadband.co.za/news/gadgets/117096-your-entire-pc-in-a-mouse.html?imm_mid=0cb2c1&cmp=em-na-na-na-newsltr_four_short_links_20150121

Comment: Why has my question been down voted?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done and it has been done. MagPi Magazine's 'Raspberry Pie Projects Book 2' features a gaming mouse with a built in zero running Quake III. You can download the book for free: https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/projects-2/

Answer (score 1):

wouldnt be possible with a Pi,

although as steve has said there is a project to create a 'pc' within a mouse. It is possible you could use something like a PS3 or Xbox remote to achieve something similar, although it would still be outside the actual control.

The Pi itself isnt exactly huge but you have to add on power supply and the wireless to it so its never going to fit inside something too small.

Comment: There is a pi zero now.  I thought of a raspberry pi in a mouse case with an HDMI cable sticking out.  You could plug it in any monitor.